# What's the difference between equity capital and market capitalization?

Tags: wealth

Is there any difference between the *equity capital* and the *market capitalization* of a company (or a bank)?

If yes then what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Equity capital = Assets − Liabilities.

Market capitalization = Number of shares outstanding × Current share price.

Comment: Thanks but I was asking about _equity capital_ not about _equity_ - a search on Google reveals that "Equity capital is funds paid into a business by investors in exchange for common or preferred stock" - which looks really different than the definition of equity and it looks very close (to me at least) to the definition of the market capitalization. I will add this text to the question, in order to make it more explicit

Comment: @JoeJobs: They mean the same things.

Comment: So Equity capital = Assets - Liabilities? And then what's the connection between that and "funds paid into a business by investors in exchange for common or preferred stock"? Because those two definitions are completely different.

Comment: You should ask a separate question.